# SQL combining different row results in one field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am seeking a means via a SQL query to combine different results from the same field, but different rows, into one field.

Example data

```
 ID    TAG 
 1234   A 
 1234   B 
 1234   C
```

Desired result:

```
 ID     TAG 
 1234   A|B|C
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: redshift is the DB I am using

Comment: Using navicat postgres against a redshift DB

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/group-concat). It includes PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon Redshift, although based on Postgres, actually supports `LISTAGG()` (which is otherwise an Oracle function).  It is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html).  So:

```
select id, listagg(tag, '|') within group (order by tag) as tags
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much Gordon!

Answer (score 1):

One method is to setup a function or stored procedure to return your value, depending on how you want to access the data. You can then setup a cursor to go through the result set, concatenate the value on each row, and then return the result value.

Microsoft has a good [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) of using cursors.

I also suggest looking at the Developer Network's other pages (you can search for your topic) because they have a lot of great information.